# Why `docker run -t` could make python flush the output buffer?

Tags: python, docker

1.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
CMD ["python", "-m", "http.server"]
```

When I execute next, you can see there is no log could be seen.

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker build -t a:1 . --no-cache
...
Successfully tagged a:1
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker run -d --name test a:1
9638189c0528fc98524b0b2f7bec72269186a3445795f0fcf974751a0d908f44
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker logs test
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$
```

2.

I struggle against above for sometime & finally find it's because of the program buffer issue, so I can fix with next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
CMD ["python", "-u", "-m", "http.server"]
```

Works now with `-u`:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker build -t a:1 . --no-cache
...
Successfully tagged a:1
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker rm -f test
test
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker run -d --name test a:1
68bc759a54ec3218b39e51404495a28d010a798b1d1e160ec7f68be3b18da9c7
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker logs test
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

3.

But when I rollback the `Dockerfile` with situation 1:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
CMD ["python", "-m", "http.server"]
```

I find with `-t` in `docker run`, the buffer also flush as next:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker build -t a:1 . --no-cache
...
Successfully tagged a:1
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker rm -f test
test
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker run -dt --name test a:1
f7cd1b5b3c272ff42c7aecd251e324b70030c046489048370689ba25b33191cc
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker logs test
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

So, my question is: why `-t` have this effect?

Comment: I think it's not python's buffer getting flushed, it's docker's output redirection. And as to the why it reacts this way.. no clue, just the general experience that docker does some magic to delegate output in order to both [properly pass signals into the running container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) as well as tie the result back to both you and the internal logs. If something weird happens with docker's output, I've just come to assume that it's because of docker being weird, and not due to the code I'm running inside of it.

Comment: In fact, after run, I check `/var/lib/docker/containers/${container_id}/${container_id}-json.log`, I can see if `docker logs empty`, this log also empty, so `python -u` flush ok really related to python program itself, but still what `docker -t` did magic to `python` to make it output at once?

Comment: The `-t` flags influence on buffering looks like an unintended side effect to me. But someone with more knowledge on docker would need to chime in to give a definitve answer.

Comment: I think `-t` makes the process appear interactive, which leads to its stdout descriptor being line-buffered, whereas it is fully buffered when run non-interactively. Can you trigger more output without using `-t` by sending requests to the server? I'd expect the output to show up via `docker logs` as soon as  more than 4096 bytes (default for libc/glibc) have been written to the descriptor's buffer. This is normally done to save costly write system calls on non-interactive command execution.

Comment: @shmee `-t makes the process appear interactive, which leads to its stdout descriptor being line-buffered, whereas it is fully buffered when run non-interactively. ` Do you have any article to support this?

Comment: If your question is wheather I have articles supporting my assumption that `-t` makes the process in the container appear interactive: no :) Hence the *I think* and the fact that I wrote a comment, instead of an answer. If you are referring to the described effect of interactivity on stdout descriptors: [Stdout Buffering](https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering), [stdio buffering](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)

Comment: @shmee Great, your suggested article resolve my problem ，it tell me `tty will make stdout line buffered`, Please post as an answer, Then I will accept, Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running a docker container with `-t/--tty` appears to attach a pseudo-terminal to the process in the container.

If an stdout descriptor is attached to a terminal, it is line buffered.
It is assumed that a user is monitoring the terminal for output of the process; printing data frequently is considered important. The buffer is flushed as soon as a newline (`\n`) character is encountered, the buffer fills up, or the process ends.

If stdout is attached to something different than a terminal, the stream is fully (or block) buffered. On libc/glibc, the default buffer size is 4096 bytes. The buffer must fill up before the its contents are flushed.
This reduces the number of expensive write system calls when it is assumed that data written to stdout will be examined later (e.g. log files).

See also [Stdout Buffering](https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering) by Evan Klitzke, [Buffering in standard streams](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) by Pádraig Brady and the [stdout man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html).