# Docker: error redirection with and without tty option

Tags: docker

Something weird happened with one of my container (a simple django app): I was unable to see the stderr stream.
After a bit of fiddling, I realised that I could make the stream appears if I added the -t option when running my container.

With that in mind, I created a simple image from a shell script :

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "all good"
echo "this is an error" >&2
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./test.sh .
CMD ["./test.sh"]
```

If I run this image without the tty option :

```
$ docker container run simple_error
```

I got this :

```
this is an error
all good
```

Now with the tty option :

```
$ docker container run -t simple_error
all good
this is an error
```

Note the stdout/stderr printing order is not the same with or without -t

I'm confused why this is happening, and why, in a more elaborate case (with my django app) I'm not able to see the error stream without the -t option.

If someone could clarify that,

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe similar to the question I asked in the past, you can see if helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930150/why-docker-run-t-could-make-python-flush-the-output-buffer